# Python tabula .convert_into skipping multiple spaces (words with multiple spaces in pdf are together without a space)

Tags: python, excel, csv, pdf, tabula

I'm using tabula.convert_into csv which grabs everything fine but text like:

"DEV__HH WorldSummit Re Estimates"

in the PDF become (There are 2 spaces between DEV and HH)

"DEVHH WorldSummit Re Estimates" in the csv

I've tried encoding='utf-8' and other libraries such as pypdf2 but tabula has given me the best results so far. It's just this one odd thing I need to resolve.

```
import tabula

file = 'input.pdf'

tabula.convert_into(file,"output.csv",pages = 'all', output_format="csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please add the string `DEV HH WorldSummit Re Estimates` correctly, because you claim there are two spaces between `DEV` and `HH`, but this is now not the case.

Comment: stackoverflow auto corrects this. That's why I added the explanation in parenthesis. If I need to elaborate further on my issue, I'd be more than happy to.